# Generic implementation of System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache

Tags: c#, generics, caching, optimization

Is there any generic alternative / implementation for MemoryCache?

I know that a MemoryCache uses a Hashtable under the hood, so all it would take is to transition into using a Dictionary<,>, which is the generic version of a Hashtable.

This would provide type safety and provide performance benefits as no boxing/unboxing.

EDIT: Another thing I'm interested in is having a different key type. The default is a System.String.

Comment: But you'd only be able to cache one type? I wouldn't worry about the cost of this too much, the boxing part will be very negligible on primitive value types.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth: Yes, that is intended. I'm wrapping the cache over a database map with sliding-expiration which returns only one type.

Comment: Then you would get no benefit other than type safety from a generic implementation. I would create a thin wrapper class around the `MemoryCache` that knows the types you are interested in, then all calling code can use the wrapper in a strongly-typed manner.

Comment: There’s something called LazyCache which is a NuGet package. The latest version seems to be in beta for almost a year but people say it’s stable.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Is there any generic alternative / implementation for MemoryCache?

Not in the base class library.  You'd have to roll your own, though I, personally, would just make a wrapper around `MemoryCache` that provides the API you wish.

> This would provide type safety and provide performance benefits as no boxing/unboxing

The type safety can be handled fairly easily in a wrapper class.  The boxing/unboxing would only be an issue if you were storing value types (not classes), and even then, would likely be minimal, as it's unlikely that you're pushing and pulling from cache often enough to have this be a true performance issue.

As for type safety and usability, I've actually written my own methods to wrap the `MemoryCache` item's calls in a generic *method*, which allows a bit nicer usage from an API standpoint.  This is very easy - typically just requires a method like:

```
public T GetItem<T>(string key) where T : class
{
    return memoryCache[key] as T;
}
```

Similarly, you can make a method to set values the same way.

> EDIT: Another thing I'm interested in is having a different key type. The default is a System.String.

This is not supported directly with `MemoryCache`, so it would require a fair bit of work to make your own key generation.  One option would be to make a type safe wrapper which also provided a `Func<T, string>` to generate a string key based off your value - which would allow you to generate a cache entry for any type `T`.  You'd have to be careful, of course, to include all data in the string that you wanted as part of your comparison, however.

Comment: I think the boxing/unboxing is a valid concern - if you are indeed caching value types. One of the main reasons to use caches is because you are calculating a value with high frequency. Hence it would be a common situation for a cache to be getting hit a lot. Maybe getting hit enough to make boxing expensive is an unusual case, but it depends how sensitive your application is to GC pressure

Comment: I don’t. It’s not.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote mine, FWIW:

<s>https://github.com/ysharplanguage/GenericMemoryCache#readme</s> (link dead)

There is a fork of the original code here:

https://github.com/caesay/GenericMemoryCache

Comment: It looks pretty interesting, a good way to revive an old question. I will certainly take a look and try this out!

Answer (score 2):

I'm working on a faster alternative to MemoryCache called [FastCache](https://github.com/jitbit/FastCache)

Supports generics for both keys and values, and the lookup speed is almost like a `Dictionary`, i.e. 7-10 times faster than `MemoryCache`

P.S. disclaimer: I'm the maintainer of the project.